# How addressing works on Macos assembler

Tags: macos, assembly, memory, addressing

I have a program in assembler language that moves all characters back 1 character. It works fine under windows, but under macos it throws a segmentation fault.

Here is the code that works under Windows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string str1 = "Hello world!";
    char* str = &str1[0];
    int str_len = str1.length();

    __asm {
        mov eax, str
        mov ecx, str_len
        dec ecx

        mov esi, eax
        add esi, ecx
        mov dl, [esi]


        shift:
            mov ebx, esi
            dec ebx
            mov al, [ebx] // ! - 11 symbol
            mov [esi], al
            dec esi
            loop shift
        mov [esi], dl
    }
    cout << str;
}
```

I heard that in mac os addressing works differently and you need to use lea and rel.
For example, this code throws a segment fault:

```
char* str = &str1[0];

__asm ​​{
mov eax, str
mov edx, [eax]
}
```

To compile on macos I use the command:
`g++ -o asm asm.cpp -fasm-blocks -std=c++17`

I will be glad for any help.

Comment: Pointers are 64-bit in x86-64 macOS, and outside the low 32 bits even for static storage, so truncating one to 32-bit (with EAX instead of RAX) makes an invalid address.

Comment: On Linux you could use `-m32` to build as 32-bit code, but macOS hasn't supported that for a few years.  (Also, `-fasm-blocks` is a clang-specific option: actual GCC doesn't support it.  macOS installs a `g++` symlink for `clang++`, which is why that works, but it's a good habit to run `clang++` when you depend on clang features, in case you ever install actual GCC, e.g. via brew.

Comment: @peter, thank you for your answer, it helped me a lot.
I rewrote the code and it worked:
char* str = &str1[0];
__asm {
    mov rax, str
    mov dl, [rax]
}